# SQL Lite Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create a table and insert values; however, I end up with an error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error".
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Login(StartTime1 TEXT  NOT NULL ,BreakBegin1 TEXT  NOT NULL, BreakEnd1 TEXT  NOT NULL, EndTime1 TEXT  NOT NULL, comments TEXT)""")

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO   Login values(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M %b-%d-%Y '),strftime(datetime.now(),'%H:%M %b-%d-%Y '),strftime(datetime.now(),'%H:%M %b-%d-%Y '),strftime(datetime.now(),'%H:%M %b-%d-%Y '),"No Comments")""")
cursor.execute("""select * from Login""")
```

Comment: Look into using a prepared statement.  Also, I disagree with the date formats you are trying to insert.  _Always_ insert dates/timestamps in an ISO format with SQLite.

Comment: What line is it showing for the error. I'm guessing the middle line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use prepared statement in your case and DATETIME for storing times:

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

now = datetime.now()

with db:
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE Login(StartTime1 DATETIME  NOT NULL,
                                BreakBegin1 DATETIME  NOT NULL,
                                BreakEnd1 DATETIME  NOT NULL,
                                EndTime1 DATETIME  NOT NULL,
                                comments TEXT)""")
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Login values(?, ?, ?, ?,"No Comments")""", 
        (now, now, now, now))

    for row in cur.execute("""select * from Login"""):
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
('2018-07-08 08:25:57.718175', '2018-07-08 08:25:57.718175', '2018-07-08 08:25:57.718175', '2018-07-08 08:25:57.718175', 'No Comments')
```